# Just started using Kohana... Have a few questions

Tags: php, kohana

I just started using Kohana a couple days ago, and I have a few questions that I cant seem to find an answer to anywhere.

Using ORM, how can you package information before you send it off? If I have a user model, and each user has a username, email, date of birth, etc... how can I package information (like add the users age as a property) before I send it to the controller?

Using ORM again, I see that if you select a user, you can also select all things related to that user (ie: articles, comments, etc.). How can you order that related information before sending it to the controller?

ie:

```
<?php
$user = ORM::factory('user', $id);
$user->articles; // holds all articles belonging to a user.

// how can you order those articles dynamically?
```

In the view, how can you get information about a user who is logged in? Do you use Auth `(Auth::instance()->get_user())`, or is there any other way?

Also, If you know any other tips/advice/qwerks about Kohana, please drop a line or two, you may answer a future question of mine.

Thanks.

**Edit:**  Another question. Using the ORM, I want to be able to load all articles that posted, in which a user has made a comment.

comments table

```
comment_id
user_id
article_id
etc....
```

Using ORM, I can access all articles posted by a user, but how would I be able to access all articles in which the user has commented on?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not using the ORM, but any other questions I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you not using the ORM? Is there something better in your opinion?

Comment: Right now, I dont have any other questions on hand.. If you have anything you'd like to share that you think I should know, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, the ORM is great for querying quickly and the ability to port to a new db. I'm just still doing my queries by hand. Are you using Kohana 2.* or 3?

Comment: I've just switched to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Kohana v3, you can order records like so:

```
$articles = ORM::factory('user', $id)->articles
                                     ->order_by('date', 'DESC')
                                     ->find_all();
```

If you are using Kohana v2, the same thing can be achieved using:

```
$articles = ORM::factory('user', $id)->orderby('date', 'DESC')
                                     ->articles;
```

And you were correct about accessing the user record through `Auth::instance()->get_user()` (if you are using the ORM Auth driver)